# Haskell: start a long running process, silently, capturing stdout

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, process, stdout

I have a long running process which I need to start.
It takes a few seconds to start, and outputs logs to stdout, with one that indicates it is ready.

I would like to:

- start the process silently, so that the stdout from the process is not displayed in my session.
- capture the output as it streams so that I can determine that it is ready.
- have some handle on the process so that I can stop the process at a later point.

I have come close using Shelly, Turtle and System.Process, but fail to capture the stdout.

Using System.Process I had:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (race)
import System.IO
import System.Process

startService :: IO ProcessHandle
startService = do
  let cmd = "./my-service"
      args = [ "-p 1234" ]
  (_, Just hout, _, p) <- createProcess $ (proc cmd args) { std_out = CreatePipe }
  started <- either id id <$> race (checkStarted hout) timeOut
  unless started $ fail "Service not started"
  pure p
  where
    checkStarted :: Handle -> IO Bool
    checkStarted h = do
      str <- hGetLine h
      -- check str for started log, else loop

    timeOut :: IO Bool
    timeOut = do
      threadDelay 10000000
      pure False
```

But The handler `hout` was never in a ready state.

Using Shelly I had:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (race)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Shelly
import System.IO

startService :: IO (Async ())
startService = do
  let cmd = "./my-service"
      args = [ "-p 1234" ]
  startedMVar <- newEmptyMVar
  async <- shelly $ asyncSh $ runHandle cmd args $ recordWhenStarted startedMVar
  started <- either id id <$> race (readMVar startedMVar) timeOut
  unless started $ fail "Service not started"
  pure async
  where
    recordWhenStarted :: MVar Bool -> Text -> IO ()
    recordWhenStarted mvar txt =
      when (isStartedLog txt) $
        modifyMVar_ mvar (const $ pure True)

    timeOut :: IO Bool
    timeOut = do
      threadDelay 10000000
      pure False
```

But the `recordWhenStarted` is never called.

Comment: Include the code you wrote so far and what's not working.

Comment: By defining `checkStarted h = True <$ hGetLine h` and replacing `"./my-service"` with `"yes"` I can get your first version to work (to actually access the handle outside the function you have to have `pure (hout, p)`). I would guess that the reason it isn't working has to do with `my-service` and not with your Haskell code.

Comment: In the terminal I just tried the 'my-service' redirecting stdout to file with no luck.
Turns out, the log output is being produced via stderr, hence why my code wasnt working

Answer (score 3):

The following is example of starting process and reading stdout [in a program of mine](https://github.com/wapxmas/mystem/blob/master/src/NLP/Mystem/IO.hs):

```
  runMystem :: [T.Text] -> IO T.Text
  runMystem stemWords = do
    (i, o, _, ph) <- createProcess (proc mystemExecutabe mystemParams) { std_in = CreatePipe, std_out = CreatePipe }
    res <- flip (maybe (return T.empty)) i $ \hIn ->
              flip (maybe (return T.empty)) o $ \hOut -> do
                hSetEncoding hIn utf8
                hSetEncoding hOut utf8
                forM_ stemWords $ TIO.hPutStrLn hIn
                TIO.hGetContents hOut
    void $ waitForProcess ph
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the [process-streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming) library (written by the author of this answer) which is a set of helpers over [process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process).

```
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# language NumDecimals #-}
import           System.Process.Streaming (execute,piped,shell,foldOut,transduce1)
import qualified System.Process.Streaming.Text as PT
import           Data.Text.Lazy (isInfixOf)
import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import           Control.Concurrent.Async
import           Control.Concurrent.MVar

main :: IO ()
main = do
    started <- newEmptyMVar
    let execution =
            execute (piped (shell "{ sleep 3 ; echo fooo ; sleep 3 ; }")) $
                foldOut . transduce1 PT.utf8x . PT.eachLine $ lookline
        lookline line = do
            when (isInfixOf "foo" line) (putMVar started ())
            return (Right ())
        stopOrNot =
            do abort <- race (threadDelay 4e6) (readMVar started)
               case abort of
                   Left () -> return () -- stop immediately
                   Right () -> runConcurrently empty -- sleep forever
    result <- race stopOrNot execution
    print result
```

[`execute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming-0.9.1.2/docs/System-Process-Streaming.html#g:1) installs exception handlers that terminate the external process when an asynchronous exceptions arrives, to it is safe to use `race` with it.

`execute` also takes care to drain any standard stream that is not read explicitly (like *stderr* in this case) to avoid a common source of deadlocks.